# Adding a on click event handler that uses an object method

Tags: javascript, oop, leaflet

I'm trying to build a wrapper JavaScript class for leaflet.  I need to bind on click events to the map (and next to buttons inside the popups) and I honestly have no idea how to do it.

I can't get the class method selectorClick() to run at all.  I need to be able to pass parameters into it as well.

Code: https://codepen.io/hendr1x/pen/GRKLjrW

```
class Map {
    self = this;
    name = '';
    elem;
    theme = 'http://b.tile.openstreetmap.fr/osmfr/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';

    constructor(name) {
        self.name = name;
        self.elem = L.map(name).fitWorld().zoomIn();
        L.tileLayer(this.theme, {
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
            maxZoom: 18,
        }).addTo(self.elem);
    }

    selector(url, message) {
        self.elem.on("click", self.selectorClick(url, message));
    }

    selectorClick(url, message) {
        alert(message);
    }
}
var mapMap = new Map('map');
mapMap.selector('/index.php', 'test message');
```

### Edit

Let me explain that the example I provided removed a lot of complexity from my actual situation because I am storing a lot on the data server. So for what we are looking at currently I have something like this in my controller

```
$this->c->map->init('mapElem');
$this->c->map->selector('/example/submit/index.php', 'You clicked this example');

which eventually echo's the following

echo "window." . $name . "Map = new Map('" . $name . "');";
echo $name . "Map.selector('" . $url . "', '" . $message . "');";
```

So with that in mind I am trying to run as much code via an external js file and send in all dynamic values as I use it (as I did above). So to answer your question I need to pass in url and message so when the map gets click I have the data to create the popup properly.

Comment: What parameters do you need to pass to it?

Comment: Wrong initialization
class Map {
    self = this;
here this always will be the window. Use this instead of self. No need this self. old way of doing same thing. else initilize in constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to handle something like this.. It all just depends on what you are wanting to accomplish.

Which parameters do you want to pass to the `selectorClick` method? What do you want to accomplish with `selectorClick`?

```js
class Map {
  constructor(id) {
    this.elem = L.map(id).fitWorld().zoomIn();
    this.name = id;
    this.theme = "http://b.tile.openstreetmap.fr/osmfr/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";
    this.url = "";
    this.message = "";
    
    this.selectorClick = this.selectorClick.bind(this);
    this.elem.on("click", this.selectorClick);
    
    L.tileLayer(this.theme, {
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
      maxZoom: 18
    }).addTo(this.elem);
  }
  
  selector(url, message) {
    this.url = url;
    this.message = message;
  }

  selectorClick(event) {//<--- event is automatically passed in because of the 'onclick' handler
    let location = event.latlng;
    alert(`POST DATA HERE:\n\n${JSON.stringify(location, null, 2)}`)
  }
}

const mapMap = new Map("map");
mapMap.selector("/index.php", "test message");
```

```css
#map { height: 180px; }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin="" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og==" crossorigin=""></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="text-align:center;">
    <h2>Click Anywhere On Map</h2>  
  </div>
  <div id="map"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I just added an edit which explains what is going on and answers your questions.  Thanks!

Comment: You can ignore my edit.  I just refactored the codepen link and got it working.  So I'm fine with how it sits now.  Can I just ask, do you have a solution that doesn't require storing a bunch of properties?  Is there no way to pass them in like parameters?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: It all depends what you're trying to do. I'm still confused as to which parameters you want to pass in. What will you be using the parameters for? What is the end goal?

Comment: So the current code pen accomplishes my goal. The idea is to have a js wrapper for map functionality.  All data needs to be passed in to the object since it is coming from server side.  To be specific, the url (to post data) and popup messaging that needs to be sent along to multiple click event listeners.  I'll take any feedback you can provide, my entire approach by bad but I can't think of a better way.  Thanks a ton.

Comment: I understand all of that.. I still do not understand *what* data you want to POST or *why* you want to POST it.. What is your ultimate goal? When a user clicks on the map to post the coordinates they clicked? What is the goal here.

Comment: Correct you got it exactly.  I want to post the lat + long coordinates that a user selects.

Comment: @hendr1x I have just updated my answer to show how you can get that data from the `onclick` event.  There's no need to pass in your own parameters - this is why I wanted to understand your goal..

Answer (score 0):

Assigning `self = this;` in the class body actually sets `self` the the scope the class is defined in instead of the `this` scope you expect it to be. If you inspect the value in your codepen, you should see it's actually the window object.

Try just using `this` instead of `self`.

Edit:

You'll also need to provide a function to the click listener. Try: `this.elem.on("click", () => self.selectorClick(url, message));`